# Can I use MTM to execute my testcases that are wriiten in Selenium Java using Eclipse IDE

Tags: selenium-webdriver, tfs, mtm

I have a application scenario where I am currently executing my test cases(written in selenium C#) using MTM, I want to know whether same can be achieved using selenium java from eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same can be achieved using `TFS 2015`, in which we can create a new build of type `ant/maven`.Once the build has been created queueing the build would result in execution of test cases on pre configured agent machine.

While creating a build we need to provide `build.xml` (for ant) or `pom.xml` (for maven) which will contain all the details specific to the project and execute the same.

Answer (score 0):

No

You can't use MTM to execute Java tests, however Microsoft is moving away form that model. This is likely because of this issue and they have already moved to using Team Build with VSTS & TFS 2015+ to execute all sorts of Functional Tests.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dgartner/2016/02/23/running-selenium-tests-as-part-of-your-release-with-vsts-release-management/

They have a specific task for this and you can now associate all automated test results with Requirements for reporting without the need for Test Cases in tge middle.

Comment: Sorry for this but I am new to this and trying to understand things. Does this mean if i get TFS 2015 plugin for eclipse i would be able to execute tests using MTM after configuring agent and controller.

Comment: No, you need to use the new Team Build system rather than the legacy XAML builds. Check out http://java.visualstudio.com