# Cucumber and Test Management Tool

Tags: cucumber

I am creating a new Automation project for which I need to come up with the Tech Stack. I am planning to opt for BDD using `Cucumber` and `Gherkin`. I wanted to know which Test management Tool I should use in this case. 
I was reading few communities where people have an opinion that we do not need a Test manager tool with `Cucumber` but my question is there could be a scenario where we have a whole lot of test cases out of which not all of them are automated.

In that case we would require a Test Repository to keep all the test cases with some flag marked as Automated.

I read this but this did not answer my question:
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2095/what-test-management-tool-to-manage-cucumber-tests?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

I was using `TestRail` for managing my team's manual test processes and also for my automation projects. You can tag your automations test with `@automation` tag and you can map them in `TestRail` as automation test cases. Hope is that works for you.

You can tag, parse and map your cucumber cases with `TestRail`'s test case id via `TestRail`'s api.

Here is the documentation of `TestRail` : http://docs.gurock.com/testrail-api2/start

Edit : 
Here is a link for your question's answer :[Can I use MTM to execute my testcases that are wriiten in Selenium Java using Eclipse IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43168163/can-i-use-mtm-to-execute-my-testcases-that-are-wriiten-in-selenium-java-using-ec)

Comment: Any other suggestions? My project is a mix of C# and jave so we have MSDN license already. I am planning to write test cases in MTM and use the Automation flag to check whether the test cases id automated or not and write the test cases in java using Eclipse. Any comments on this approach?

Comment: I can only suggest this for now. @Neha

Comment: @Neha hi again, TFS tool can help you to achieve your issue.  I added the Stack Overflow link of solution.

Comment: @Neha If this solution was your answer please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`TestRail` is a widely used test management tool nowadays, where you can add your cucumber dsl and later attach it with your automation scenarios. You can integrate it easily with the below ruby gem, if you are a `Ruby` user.

---

## Ruby

---

[testrail-cucumber](https://rubygems.org/gems/testrail-cucumber)

#### Install gem file

```
gem 'testrail-cucumber'
```

#### Import the library in your env file

```
require 'testrail-cucumber'
```

#### Sync Case ID in your BDD scenario

Prefix TestRail Case ID on start of your cucumber scenario; say, C860

```
  @your_tag
  Scenario: C860 Verify the home page
    Given I navigate to "home" page
    Then I verify the home page
```

#### Config TestRail details

- Create a testrail config file, `testrail_config.yml` in the project parent folder
- Fill up the testrail details on right hand side of the fields (url, user, password, and run_id); `run_id` is the dynamically generated id from your testrail account (say, `run_id: 111`)

```
testrail:
  url: https://your_url.testrail.io/
  user: your@email.com
  password: your_password
  run_id: your_run_id
```

#### Update the results through `Hooks` on end of each test

```
After do |scenario|
  TestrailCucumber::UpdateTestRails.new(scenario).upload_result
end
```